# Parallel execution of curses in different windows...(using ncurses)

Tags: c, ncurses

I have been trying to create `pong` game using `ncurses` library on a `terminal`. I have successfully created the two bars for both the players. The problem is that when both the players press their corresponding keys, only one of them was moving.

So, I searched the net and found that we can use windows, where we can have `logical curser` to each window and hence execute the commands from the players parallely. The code-snippet of my program looks as follows:

```
pthread_t player_1, player_2;
pthread_create(&player_1, NULL, (void*)&player_1_move, (void*)pl_window);
pthread_create(&player_2, NULL, (void*)&player_2_move, (void*)p2_window);

while(1)
{
    char c=getch();
    if(key is from p1)
         //signal player_1 thread to refresh the bar position

    if(key is from p2)
         //refresh it for player_2 by signaling 2nd thread..

}
//here player_1_move and player_2_move are the functions for changing the bar position         for each of the players..I have created two windows in which i draw these bars, which i haven't shown in my code..
```

The problem is that though I use the pthreads, i still can't see both moving simultaneously, when both players press at-a-time.

Any suggestions plz...

Comment: @ta.speot.is Window doesn't imply a separate one. Its a part of the same terminal..itself.. :)

Comment: Something tells me you don't need pthreads to implement Pong....

Comment: I'm pretty certain that there is no "more than one key pressed" for terminals.

Comment: I think you have 2 potential problems but without more details I can't be sure. 1) ncurses is not generally thread safe so your threads may be causing problems. 2) ncurses does not handle 2 keys being pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Craig said... a terminal doesn't handle when 2 keys are pressed at the same time. It will choose any one of them.. That was the exact problem. and can't be resolved even if we use `pthreads`.